# multiple selector $(document) and more element

Tags: jquery

Are we able to have $(document) and $('#moreID') together?
Like

```
$(document), $('#moreID').on('click',function().......)
```

Googled and [Api docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) doesn't really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that there is an [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method that can be used to add selectors.

In your case:

```
$(document).add('#moreID').on('click', '#element', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `document`, I assume what you intend is `document.body`.  If so, then you can just use a comma in your string to delimit selectors.

```
$('body, #moreID').on('click', function() { /* ... */ });
```